# Trying to count the first occurrence of each word in each row of a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have over 100 rows of survey data where respondents typed their responses to open-ended questions. To analyze their responses, I want to create a word cloud for each question. My idea to do this is to count the unique words in each response and then add them together to try and see what words respondents were saying the most. For example, if respondent 1 says "angry" and respondent 2 says "angry", then concatenating the two lists would result in the word "angry" appearing twice. The situation I'm looking to avoid is if one person uses one word multiple times, I don't want their multiple uses of that word to skew the data. If someone says the word "angry" 100 times but nobody else uses it, then that word isn't representative of the sentiments of all the respondents. I would then feed this data into the word cloud program.

To start, I imported the excel data into a pandas DataFrame and then isolated the answers to the first question

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

df = pd.read_excel("./Data - Open Ended Questions.xlsx", sheet_name="Working Data")

df1 = df['question1']
```

Next, I tried iterating through each response in the series. The following program returns the unique words from the first response, but I'm not sure how to return the results from the other responses. I'm thinking I need to create a list for each response and append them together, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

```
def words(df):
    l = list()
    
    for index, response in df.items():
            response = response.lower()
            words = response.split()
            
            for word in words:
                if word in l:
                    l
                else:
                    l.append(word)
            return l

words(df1)
```

User Zombro led me onto the right track with their response. My finalized solution is below.

```
def unique_words_per_response(series):
    # convert to lowercase to combine words like "The" and "the"
    series = series.str.lower()
    
    # remove punctuation using the String package
    series = series.str.translate(response.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))
    
    # Zombro's solution
    series = series.apply(lambda series: pd.Series(series.split()).unique()).explode()
    
    # convert words to capitalize first letter of each word to look better in word cloud
    series = series.str.capitalize()
    
    # join words with spaces to create one single string
    series = ' '.join(series.tolist())

    return series
```

Comment: Add your expected output with sample data?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first word from each row like,

```
df['question1'].apply(lambda x:x.split()[0])
```

Edit-1:

Based on OP's comment, to get unique words without punctuation

```
data = {'q1': ["Hello, world!", 
               "This is a sample sample sentence.", 
               "Pandas Pandas is great!"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
unique_words = set(" ".join(df['q1'].str.lower().str.translate(translator).values).split())
```

---

**Output:**

```
{'hello', 'pandas', 'this', 'a', 'great', 'is', 'sample', 'sentence', 'world'}
```

Comment: and without the lambda, `df["question1"].str.split().str[0]`

Comment: @jkr This was new and got confused with `.str[0]`, `.split()` returns list, how `.str` was able to access each row value as a list, ideally, It should be a string of list, right? like `str(['w1', 'w2',...])` Can you explain?

Comment: i cannot explain it well but here are the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings

Comment: I'm not looking to just get the first word from each row. I need to iterate over each row to retrieve the UNIQUE words from each response as a list and then concatenate the lists to feed into the word cloud program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to create word clouds for each question, you'll need to process each response separately and then combine the results. Firstly, move the return statement outside of the loop, to actually return all the responses, and not just first one. Now, let's try to modify your peace of code;

```
for index, response in df.items():
```

Then, looking at the loop itself, we need to iterate through the items in the df, and finally we just.

```
response = response.lower()
```

In this loop, we convert response to lower case, to ensure that the word frequency count is case-insensitive,

```
words = response.split()
unique_words.append(set(words))
```

after we make a list of words out of the response we got,and finally we add the results to the list variable **l** (if you use set(), it will remove the duplicates).

```
combined_words_set = set().union(*unique_words)
```

As we got our words, we do a little manipulation, specifically, we require to combine all the sets to single set,

```
unique_words_list = list(combined_words_set)
```

afterwards, we achieve the final result through set into a list
That's all I could to say, hope it helps you)

the code should look like this:

```
def words(df):
unique_words = [] # rename l into unique_words for clearity

for index, response in df.items():
    response = response.lower()
    words = response.split()
    unique_words.append(set(words))

combined_words_set = set().union(*unique_words)

unique_words_list = list(combined_words_set)

return unique_words_list

unique_words_question1 = words(df1)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following your code. Can you combine it to show what it should look like in the editor? As it stands, it looks like you eliminate the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a solution like this ? clarifying your question with some example dataset would help.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
    "example response 1",
    "another response",
    "another example response",
    "vanilla bean"
])


s.apply(lambda s: s.split()).explode().value_counts()


>>> 
response    3
example     2
another     2
1           1
vanilla     1
bean        1
dtype: int64
```

i think the key to this solution is denormalizing your data and then leveraging `Series.explode` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. The situation I'm looking to avoid is if one person uses one word multiple times, I don't want their multiple uses of that word to skew the data. If someone says the word "angry" 100 times but nobody else uses it, then that word isn't representative of the sentiments of all the respondents. I'll update the post to clarify this.

Comment: perhaps then this is more viable:  `s.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.split()).unique()).explode().value_counts()`

Comment: Ok, this shows me what the end result should look like. But the useful thing about my for loop was that I can use `.lower()` to make every word case insensitive, I can use a method to eliminate punctuation, and by appending all the words into a list I can join the list to get a new string to input into the word cloud program. I don't believe I can do all of those things to a series without a for loop, but I'm sure I'm wrong. Edit: Actually, I already see I'm wrong about `.lower()`.

Comment: Think I've got it now. I was able to make all the manipulations necessary and believe the word counts are correct. I will update my post with my finalized code as soon as I finish it. Thanks for the help!